# GetAllIncluding Include last record of related table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, aspnetboilerplate

```
 var kitContents = await _kitItemRepository.GetAllIncluding(ki => ki.Campaign, ki => ki.Item, ki => ki.Comments.LastOrDefault()).Where(ki=>ki.KitId == input.kitId).ToListAsync();
```

I'm expecting that only the last record (given there are comments) but, it is throwing an error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The Include property lambda expression 'ki => {ki.Comments => LastOrDefault()}' is invalid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter of the target type, E.g. '(Derived d) => d.MyProperty'. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.'

Answer (score 1):

you can not use `LastOrDefault()` like that. get all comments and remove all except the last.